# How do I redirect(301) url containing question mark

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect url from another site which contains question mark(?) in it. It redirecting to new url, but appends string after question mark to new url.

eg. my old site url is

```
 www.example.com/test/new-test?xyz
```

want to redirect to

```
www.abc.com/lorem
```

It redirecting to new url but appending `?xyz` to new url.
After redirection new url looks like as below.

```
www.abc.com/lorem?xyz.
```

I did following changes in .htaccess file.

```
Redirect 301 /test/new-test?xyz www.abc.com/lorem
```

Can anyone suggest how can I redirect it to `www.abc.com/lorem`

Answer (score 0):

QueryString isn't part of match in Redirect directive. You need to use mod-rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} xyz
RewriteRule ^test/new-test/?$ /loerm? [L,R]
```

**?** at the end of the destination is important as it removes the old query strings.

Comment: still it is appending ? at end of redirected url